# Swift Calling Array in Module

Tags: ios, class, swift

I am trying to separate my tableview logic from my view controller and have a swift file that contains my tableviews array data. I am now trying to access this array from the class I created in my swift file within my view controller, but I'm not sure of the right way to call this information and set it to a variable. Found below is how I'm currently calling it, but I receive a warning, `Variable 'friendsFeed' inferred to have type '()', which my be unexpected`. This doesn't seem to be the right way to do this.

Here is my tableview logic, FriendsFeed.swift:

```
import Foundation

public class FriendsFeedTableView {

    var friendsDict: [String: String] = ["Username":"Mike Duff", "Bar": "Old Town Tavern"]


    init(friendsDict: [String: String]){
        self.friendsDict = friendsDict
    }

}
```

Here is my view controller which contains the tableview:

```
import UIKit

class SegmentedControlViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!


    @IBOutlet weak var eventImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var primaryEventLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        feedTableView.delegate = self

        feedTableView.dataSource = self


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func feedListChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:

                var friendsFeed = FriendsFeedTableView(friendsDict: <#[String : String]#>);)



            println("Friends Selected")

            case 1:

            println("Friends in Area Selected")

            case 2:

            println("Top Events Selected")

            default:

            break

        }
    }







}
```

Comment: Don't construct views in `feedListChanged`. Instead, construct them all and assign to properties in `viewDidLoad` and set `hidden` accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your FriendsFeedTableView is supposed to store the data that you display in your table view? It contains a dictionary, which will not work as a data structure for storing table view contents. Dictionaries are unordered collections, and a table view requires that its contents be stored in a fixed order.

You can create a separate class that has an array property to store the data for your table view (or an array of arrays, if you want to use a table view with multiple sections.

You can make each object in your array a dictionary, struct, or custom data object to store the data to be displayed in your table view if that fits your design.

If you want a separate object to serve as the model for your table view you should consider having your object serve as the data source for your table view. The datasource methods for UITableView are a little strange in that one of those methods actually serves up table view cells, which are view objects. In my view that blurs the line between model and controller.

Lots of people (myself included) use an array (or an array of arrays for a sectioned table view) as their model, and simply store that array as a property of the view controller. In this case the view controller **has a** model object, but it is not itself a model object.

The view controller still does its job of mediating between the model (the array of data) and the view (the table view and its cells.)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm still trying to figure out the most efficient way of creating this table functionality. Thank you for making me understand that dictionaries do not work as data structures for storing table view content. Makes sense now. In general, I have three segemented controls controlling table views with three different data sources. I was thinking best practices would be to create three classes to handle the different data. Would this be the best approach?

Comment: Best approach? Hard to say. I would lean towards using 3 different arrays, and some way of selecting the array. You could store your 3 table arrays in an outer array, you could store them in a dictionary with the key being the table view object: You could make them separate instance variables and use a switch statement to select the correct one...